# How to align table border with div border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the black bar from the table td reach out all the way to the black border of the div. what am I doing wrong? I've been messing around with this for a while now and its starting to get to me. :( I've included all the css and html below. Hopefully someone can give me a hand with this. Thanks in advance!

```html
<div style="background: #DCDCDC;border: 1px solid #000000;border-radius: 12px; vertical-align: top;width: 240px;height: 180px;">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#000000" height="15"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the table just to make the black border?

Comment: i think it would be great if you can post a simple mock-up of the end result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `overflow: hidden` to hide the style outside of the parent.

`border-spacing: 0` to remove the default spacing of the table.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background: #DCDCDC;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 240px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td bgcolor="#000000" height="15"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>f</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I remember doing it another way for some reason. =)